# Excel VBA - calling global variables by concatenated name

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I have these

```
Public Const WS1 = "SheetNameA"
Public Const WS2 = "SheetNameB"
Public Const WS3 = "SheetNameC"
Public Const WS4 = "SheetNameD"
Public Const WS5 = "SheetNameE"
Public Const WS6 = "SheetNameF"
```

Where SheetNameA-B-C are the names of sheets in a workbook.
And I would like to activate worksheets one after the other using a `For loop 1 to 6`like so:

```
For i = 1 to 6
    Workbooks([wbkname]).Sheets(WS & i).Activate
    [some more code doing stuff]
Next i
```

Now I know that doesn't work, I'm just trying to explain what I want.
Is that possible? To call a public constant by a concatenated name (to make that public constant string the name of the sheet we're activating)?

I hope that makes sense.

Edit: On second thought, maybe I'll just do a `Select Case`, which I know is not pretty, but I think, will be fine for my purpose.

```
For i = 1 to 6
    Select Case i
        Case 1
            somevariable = [name of one sheet]
        Case 2
            somevariable = [name of another sheet]
        ....
    End Select
    Workbooks([wbkname]).Sheets(somevariable).Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of an "indirect" function in VBA, what you can do is to define a public array and store the values there, here you can get the values by index. As its not possible to define array constants in VBA you need to initialize your array before use (e.g. In the workbook's load event).

Answer (score 0):

Just use an array.  First run **MAIN()**, then run **marine()**:

```
Public WS(1 To 6) As String

Sub MAIN()
   WS(1) = "SheetNameA"
   WS(2) = "SheetNameB"
   WS(3) = "SheetNameC"
   WS(4) = "SheetNameD"
   WS(5) = "SheetNameE"
   WS(6) = "SheetNameF"
End Sub

Sub marine()
   For i = 1 To 6
       Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(WS(i)).Activate
       [some more code doing stuff]
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's an absolutely great suggestion - it might not work for me though. In my case, let's say in one workbook I have sheets like (off the top of my head, random stuff): "People", "Animals", "Plants", whereas in the other workbook i'll have multiple related sheets to each one of those, like "Data - People", "Stuff - People", "Whatever - People", and I even wanna add the prefix into the mix, activating "People" in one wbk, and then "Data - People" in the other.

Comment: @metrazol  You can make the array elements anything you choose.